# Definable sets in infinite structures

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

Working in first order logic, let $\mathcal{M} = (M,I)$ be an $\mathcal{L}_A$-structure, where $A$ consists only of the unary function symbol $F_1$ (here, $M$ is the universe and $I: \{x_i\} \rightarrow M$ the interpretation of variables in $M$).  I was asked to come up with

1. an example of an infinite $\mathcal{M}$ in which every singleton $\{m\}$ in $M$ is definable, and
2. an example of an infinite $\mathcal{M}$ in which no nonempty finite subset of $M$ is definable.

I was hoping to clear up some of my confusion related to the meaning of "$A$ consists only of $F_1$" which seems to be holding me up:

If I take this to mean that $A$ also includes the symbol $\hat{=}$, then can I not take care of (1) right off the bat and make $\{m\}$ trivially definable from parameters in the set $\{m\}$ using $\varphi(x_1, x_2) := (x_1 \hat{=} x_2)$?  Then only those $\mathcal{M}$-assignments $\nu$ with $\nu(x_2) = m = \nu(x_1)$ witness membership in $\{m\}$. And I don't see how any automorphism of $\mathcal{M}$ can expand the set definable via $\varphi[m,m]$ beyond $\{m\}$, since $m$, itself a parameter here, must be a fixed point of any such automorphism.

But then under this reading, how do I block against definability of singletons in the second case whatever the $\mathcal{M}$?  The $\varphi(x_1, x_2)$ above seems to work whatever the $\mathcal{M}$ unless I am grossly misunderstanding the satisfaction notion for formulas of the form $(a \hat{=} b)$.

[And even so, I don't see how I could read "$A$ consists only of $F_1$" to mean that $A$ excludes the symbol "$\hat{=}$".  If I excluded $\hat{=}$ from $A$, how would anything be definable? I wouldn't even have $\mathcal{L}_A$-formulas to define things with, since giving up $\hat{=}$ and predicate symbols I would not even be able to form the atomic formulas, right?]

Comment: Perhaps by definable they mean definable over $\varnothing$, i.e. without parameters? That way 1. is not so trivial and 2. is possible.

Comment: @Adayah Ah, that might be so.  Does anything jump out as incorrect to you in my question?  In particular, am I right in thinking that the $\varphi$ above would cause a problem for 2 if "definable" here means definable from parameters in a nonempty subset of $M$?

Comment: Regardless of whether we allow parameters, we don't mean "definable *in a nonempty subset*" when we say "definable," so that is wrong.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Sure, thank you.  I meant my follow-up question to Adayah's comment as more of a hypothetical to check that the formula saying "I am $m$" would indeed be problematic for 2 if I were to misread "definable" (as I did as you both have pointed out) as definable $\textit{from}$ parameters in a nonempty subset of the universe.

Comment: I'm just not sure where the "in a nonempty subset of the universe" came from in the first place - it's not part of the question explicitly, and it's not part of the definition of definability (from parameters or not).

Comment: @NoahSchweber I guess I'm confused too--I was using that phrase to emphasize not definable without parameters.  I guess I should have also said in my last comment that in my notes from this course here at Berkeley the definition of definability is broken up into two cases: definable from parameters in a subset of the universe of the structure, and definable without parameters i.e. definable from the empty set.  Sorry I omitted this, but I only looked back at this after Adayah commented.  With that in mind, did I say something fallacious?

Comment: @youngbuck25 Oh, I think I see what's going on! In the phrase "definable with parameters in some subset of the universe," the part "some subset of the universe" means that the *parameters* are required to come from that subset. E.g. in $(\mathbb{R}; <)$, the open interval $S=(0,1)$ is definable from parameters in the set $(-1, 2)$ - namely, $S=\{y: 0<y\wedge y<1\}$ (the parameters here are $0$ and $1$, and each parameter is in the set $(-1, 2)$). In other words, it's "definable with (parameters in some set)," not "(definable with parameters) in some set."

Comment: @NoahSchweber Right, sorry I was not clear about that.  This is why parentheses are useful in logic and life I guess.  But with that in mind I'm not making things up when I say that the $\varphi$ above would cause trouble for (2) under my misreading, right?

Comment: @youngbuck25 Yes, quite right.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider "definable without parameters" then you can consider:
- $(\mathbb N,<)$ in which every singleton is definable,
- $(\mathbb Z,<)$ in which no non-empty finite set is definable.